# Holomorphicity of $f(x + iy) = x^2 + iy^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, derivatives, complex-numbers, partial-derivative

By definition:

> $f: E \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, where $E$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic on $E$ if $f$ is $\mathbb{C}$-differentiable at all points of $E$.

The key point being that $E$ is open.

Looking at the function $f(x + iy) = x^2 + iy^2$, we can show, by using the Cauchy-Riemann equations, that $f$ is $\mathbb{C}$-differentiable on the line $y = x$.

But my lecture notes say that this line does not contain any open sets, so $f$ is not holomorphic anywhere.

Why does the line not contain any open sets? Can we not just pick $E$ to be some open interval of the line?

Additionally, the lecture notes rewrite $f$ in terms of $z$ and $\overline{z}$, where $\overline{z}$ is the complex conjugate of $z \in \mathbb{C}$, to give $f(x + iy) = \frac{1}{4} ((z + \overline{z})^2 - i(z - \overline{z})^2)$

What is the benefit of rewriting $f$ in this way? Does it help us determine the holomorphicity of $f$?

Comment: Open intervals of the line are not open sets of $\Bbb{C}$. "does not contain any open set" means that it does not contain any open disk.

Comment: Ah, of course, since $E \subset \mathbb{C}$ we care about open sets in $\mathbb{C}$. Do you by any chance have any insight into the rewriting of $f$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the open set of $\mathbb{C}$ is the unions of a family of open balls $\bigcup B(z,r)$ ,where $B(z,r):=\{w \in \mathbb{C}:|w-z|<r\}$, dual to the topological structure of $\mathbb{C}$.

The open interval of the line is so called the subspace topology of the line on $\mathbb{C}$, but is not on $\mathbb{C}$.

We say $f$ is holomorphic at the point $z=z_0$,means $f$ is differentiable on some neighborhood of $z=z_0$. Since $f$ is not differentiable on any neighborhood of any $z$ on the line, it is obvious $f$ is not holomorphic on the line.

Rewriting $f$ in terms of $z$ and $\overline{z}$ helps us to know its holomorphicity on connected open sets $G$. Since $f$ is holomorphic on $G$ iff $f$ is real differential and $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}}=0$ on $G$.

Regarding the rewriting of $f$:

First suppose that $f=u+iv$ is real differentiable (which means that the real and imaginary parts of $f$ are differentiable), then $u(z_0+\Delta z)−u(z_0)=\frac{\partial u(z_0)}{\partial x}\Delta x + \frac{\partial u(z_0)}{\partial y}\Delta y+|\Delta z|$. Also, we have a similar formula of $v$.

Then rewrite $\Delta x = \frac{\Delta z + \Delta \overline{z}}{2}, \Delta y= \frac{\Delta z +\Delta \overline{z}}{2i}$ and introduce operator $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-i \frac{\partial}{\partial y})$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}}=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+i \frac{\partial}{\partial y})$.

Hence we have $f(z_0 + \Delta z)-f(z_0)= \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(z_0) \Delta z + \frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}}(z_0) \overline{\Delta z}+ o(|\Delta z|)$. Comparing to the definition of the differentiability of $f$, we then have the conclusion.